# How to get a list of entities available in your Drupal?

Tags: 7, entities

Sometimes I need to create a new entity but I don't know the exact machine name of the entity to put in the `entity_create()` method.

Is there an easy way to check which entity types are available to create in your Drupal 7 site?

Comment: This is for Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 ?

Comment: it's for drupal 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just invoke `hook_entity_info()` and check the keys:

```
$info = module_invoke_all('entity_info');
$all_entity_machine_names = array_keys($info);
```